# Update field in one table based on values in another table

Tags: ms-access

I have a status field in a table in which test steps are marked as `pass` or `fail` and in another table I have to update test case(testID) as `pass` if all test step(testID) are `pass`, and `fail` test case if one of test is `fail`.

I have `testID` field common in both tables.

In the 1st table one column is `testID` and 5 steps are corresponding to that test ID and they can be `pass` or `fail`.

In the 2nd table I have one column in which I have to mark status as `pass` or `fail` based on overall 5 steps.

#### Table 1

[image: X]

#### Table 2

[image: X]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following queries perform the update in two steps: the 1st query updates those tests which exist and pass, and the 2nd query updates those tests which exist and fail.

#### Update 'passed' tests:

```
update table1 t1
set t1.teststatus = 'pass'
where t1.testID in
(
    select t2.testID
    from table2 t2
    group by t2.testID
    having min(t2.status) = max(t2.status) and min(t2.status) = 'pass'
)
```

#### Update 'failed' tests:

```
update table1 t1
set t1.teststatus = 'fail'
where t1.testID in
(
    select t2.testID
    from table2 t2
    where t2.status = 'fail'
    group by t2.testID
)
```

Comment: steps are not constant for all test cases. for  some test case I have 5 steps and for some 7,for some 11.

Comment: steps are not constant for all test cases. for some test case I have 5 steps and for some 7,for some 11.for some steps pass or fail is not there means validation is not there for those steps so they have null values neither pass nor fail

Comment: @ravi Please edit your question to include some sample data.

Comment: ID TestID stepid status
1 456          1           pass
2 456          2           pass
3 456    3         pass
4 457    1       fail
5 457        2           fail

Comment: 1st table                                                                                                        TestID testStatus
456         this need to update
457

Comment: I have attached screenshot of tables in this thread kindly have a look

Comment: if  status column is blank for particular test ID in table 2 then also this code update pass in table 1 corresponding to that test ID. for table image I am refering your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53353726/why-is-this-query-not-updateable?noredirect=1&lq=1  Suppose in table 2 and stepID 1 and 2 corresponding to testID 2 is blank then this query update for that also.My expectation is it should be blank.