# Why is this Query not Updateable?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I was looking to provide an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53337213/7531598) in which the OP has two tables:

#### Table1

```
+--------+--------+
| testID | Status |
+--------+--------+
|      1 |        |
|      2 |        |
|      3 |        |
+--------+--------+
```

#### Table2

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| ID | testID | stepID | status |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 |      1 |      1 | pass   |
|  2 |      1 |      2 | fail   |
|  3 |      1 |      3 | pass   |
|  4 |      2 |      1 | pass   |
|  5 |      2 |      2 | pass   |
|  6 |      3 |      1 | fail   |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
```

Here, the OP is looking to update the `status` field for each `testID` in Table1 with `pass` if the `status` of all `stepID` records associated with the `testID` in Table2 have a `status` of `pass`, else Table1 should be updated with `fail` for that `testID`.

In this example, the result should be:

```
+--------+--------+
| testID | Status |
+--------+--------+
|      1 | fail   |
|      2 | pass   |
|      3 | fail   |
+--------+--------+
```

---

I wrote the following SQL code in an effort to accomplish this:

```sql
update Table1 a inner join 
(
    select 
        b.testID, 
        iif(min(b.status)=max(b.status) and min(b.status)='pass','pass','fail') as v
    from Table2 b 
    group by b.testID
) c on a.testID = c.testID
set a.testStatus = c.v
```

However, MS Access reports the all-too-familiar, 'operation must use an updateable query' response.

I know that a query is not updateable if there is a one-to-many relationship between the record being updated and the set of values, but in this case, the aggregated subquery would yield a one-to-one relationship between the two `testID` fields.

Which left me asking, why is this query not updateable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're joining in a query with an aggregate (`Max`).

Aggregates are not updateable. In Access, in an update query, every part of the query has to be updateable (with the exception of simple expressions, and subqueries in `WHERE` part of your query), which means your query is not updateable.

You can work around this by using domain aggregates (`DMin` and `DMax`) instead of real ones, but this query will take a large performance hit if you do.

You can also work around it by rewriting your aggregates to take place in an `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS` clause, since that's part of the `WHERE` clause thus doesn't need to be updateable. That would likely minimally affect performance, but means you have to split this query in two: 1 query to set all the fields to "pass" that meet your condition, another to set them to "fail" if they don't.

Comment: Thank you Erik! _"every part of the query has to be updateable"_ This was the gap in my understanding.

Comment: Update queries in Access are _very_ different than in SQL server and other RDBMSes. They come with that limitation (at least everything that's available in the `SELECT` clause), but they do allow for merging and updating multiple tables in a single query, something that just can't be done in many RDBMSes